# Youtube player not working in the production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, youtube-api, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement a youtube player in my web application. For this i have used the following react library

**react-youtube**
https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube

I have implemented it and working in the localhost without any issue. But it stops working in the production build. It gives out an error like the following

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

What causes this and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your production server is only allowing you to embed scripts which is coming from its own origin, or `script-src 'self'`.

This is done using the `Content-Security-Policy` either as a response header, HTML meta tag or `manifest.json` file. Please check with the network inspector where this CSP is set. If you are running on a CloudFront or other content network you need to configure it to allow it.

You need to extend this to allow YouTube, eg. extending it like `script-src 'self' youtube.com;`